# jQuery - Updating a sortable list after sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a list item and in each list item is a `span` tag looking like this `<span class="pos">1st</span>` That goes from `1` to `5`. So it'd be 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th.

It's a sortable list, so after you sort. I wanted it to update each `span` tag correctly with number and suffix. However, in the jsFiddle below, you will see that is not the case.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weka/4GN37/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
update: function (event, ui) {
    $(".list span.pos").html(function(i) {
        var suf = ["st", "nd", "rd"];
        return (i + 1) + (suf[i] || "th");
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4GN37/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.list').children().each(function(i) {
    $('.pos', this).text(i + 1);
    this.id = 'item-' + (i + 1); // ids cannot start with a number
    // but changing ids is often a bad idea...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/hhFYz/1/

For the suffix you can simply write a function which returns the proper suffix for a given number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X58cu/1/) that fixes your problem. The problem is that in your loop you just referenced the children by their existing id which didn't change. You needed to reference them by their new child position.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var children = $('ul.list').children();
while (loopy < 6) {
    //$("li#" + loopy + ".rank > span.pos").text(loopy);
    $('span.pos', children[loopy-1]).text(loopy);
    console.log("Set pos..... " + loopy);
    $(children[loopy-1]).attr("id", loopy);
    loopy++;
} // end loop
```